# Get the default Firefox profile directory from bash

Tags: firefox, bash

I'm trying to get the profile directory of the default firefox profile (the one that opens automatically) from Bash. How could I proceed? I can't find any useful options issuing `firefox --help`

Comment: you can du a `firefox; sudo lsof | grep [username] | grep firefox | grep profile` which would get a firefox instance running. `lsof` will show you the opened files; `grep` will filter you out the interesting parts of `lsof`. This will quickstart the info + needs some fine-tuning. What do you need the information for anyhow? Do you wanna put some  stuff automatically in a firefox profile folder - why?

Comment: I want to get the firefox decmod.db file, because it is needed for a Java web application. For some reason, it works out of the box on Windows, but a configuration file with the path to the decmod.db file should be placed at home on Linux. I want to generate this file automatically.

Comment: Sorry, can't edit my previous comment. Your proposal "works", but I want to place this on a session start script (for several reasons, it's the only place that makes sense) and I don't want to run firefox on each session start.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try `grep 'Path=' ~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini | sed s/^Path=//`. Default profile folder name is stored in `profiles.ini`. This will work fine while you've got single profile.
If you have more than one Firefox profile then the file format changes, so extracting the folder name becomes more tricky. Here's the script to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/
if [[ $(grep '\[Profile[^0]\]' profiles.ini) ]]
then PROFPATH=$(grep -E '^\[Profile|^Path|^Default' profiles.ini | grep -1 '^Default=1' | grep '^Path' | cut -c6-)
else PROFPATH=$(grep 'Path=' profiles.ini | sed 's/^Path=//')
fi

echo $PROFPATH
```

This script will work in both cases, it selects the appropriate method depending on the amount of profiles. Works in OSX, too.

Comment: Apparently now the default profile is the one in profiles.ini that has the line `Default=1` and it can be anywhere in the file (first, middle, last).

Comment: @Xen2050 Are you sure? I checked 2 different profiles from Ubuntu & Windows machines. Both have no `Default=1` line. Both have `[Profile0]` section with `Name=default` in them instead. Can you provide your `profiles.ini` using http://paste.ubuntu.com ?

Comment: It's just got that one extra line, under the 2nd profile actually. I've changed my default profile using the profile manager, try using it too (with the -p option) and see if it changes on yours. There must be related  info pages on mozilla.org, but I'm not able to search right now.

Comment: Did find a link, mentions it along with don't ask/show profile manager & use last selected profile to change the default  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profiles.ini_file

Comment: @Xen2050 Added script to process multi-profile `profiles.ini`.

Comment: This is not working for me (OSX), with [this profiles.ini](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23989307/). It returns the second one, instead of the first. Thanks.

Comment: That's strange. Saved your `profiles.ini`, run the command `tr < profiles.ini ... \1/'` from my script in the terminal and it correctly extracted the path from the default profile. What line ends do you use in your OSX?

Comment: Found an answer. OSX uses POSIX `sed` while Ubuntu uses gnu `sed` with some extensions: http://superuser.com/q/307165. POSIX `sed` treats bracket expressions differently: http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html . So this algorithm won't work in OSX, as it depends on proper brackets handling (in terms of gnu `sed`). POSIX way of brackets handling is limited in comparison with gnu way.

Comment: @sebastien.b I tried another approach. Can you test the next command: `grep -E '^\[Profile|^Path|^Default' profiles.ini | grep -1 '^Default=1' | grep '^Path' | cut -c6-` ? It depends on `grep` only and works for multi-profile `profiles.ini`. Both Ubuntu and OSX use GNU `grep`, so they should work the same way. If it works, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Does not work on OSX, unless you specify `~/Library/Application Support//Firefox/profiles.ini` as a source.

Answer (score 7):

Your default profile directory is stored under home directory.

```
cd ~/.mozilla/firefox
```

Here you will find something like **xxxxxxxx.default**. This is the location where all your personal data is stored.

You can run the command `firefox -P` to show the profiles available and select one from the list.

Comment: The correct dir should be `.mozilla`

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, `find $HOMEDIR/.mozilla/firefox/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -name *.default | head -1`. But that CAN fail. It's not a good way to do it.

Comment: @JorgeSuárezdeLis Could you explain in what scenarios this can fail? Not disagreeing, but I'd like to know.

Comment: It will fail if the user has more than one profile and it is not using the one named `whatever.default`

Answer (score 1):

I know that this a little older, but in case someone else also needs this information, here is how I set the default profile variable in a wrapper script for firefox:

```
def_Pfile=`cat "$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini" | sed -n -e 's/^.*Path=//p' | head -n 1`
```

Hope this helps, as it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It works like a charm on linux.

My **profile.ini**

```bsh
cat "$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini"                                         
[Install4F96D1932A9F858E]
Default=4hthy81n.default-release
Locked=1

[Profile1]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=t6kac19e.default
Default=1

[Profile0]
Name=default-release
IsRelative=1
Path=4hthy81n.default-release

[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1
Version=2
```

So run this command:

```bsh
grep "Default=.*\.default*" "$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini" | cut -d"=" -f2
```

about:profiles:

[image: about:profiles]