# How do I change Firefox's `about:config` from a shell script?

Tags: firefox, scripts, configuration

On of the first things I do when first using a fresh Firefox profile, is to set `browser.urlbar.trimURLs` to `false` (which really should be changeable though ‘Preferences’ or should have remained default), and to [change the search and homepage defaults to DuckDuckGo](http://help.dukgo.com/customer/portal/articles/216441). Currently I manually go to `about:config`, click through the angry warning message, and search for the keys (which unlike in DConf Editor, aren't even organised).

So I would like to know how to read and write these keys from the command-line so that I can add these tweaks to my customisations script.

Comment: Some answers below rely on editing a file in the user's `profile.default` folder. Here's how you find it from within a shell script: [Get the default Firefox profile directory from bash](http://askubuntu.com/questions/239543/get-the-default-firefox-profile-directory-from-bash)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38591/how-to-change-a-firefox-option-on-a-quick-way-via-shortcuts-command-line | single session: http://superuser.com/questions/699136/how-can-one-change-a-firefox-config-setting-from-the-cli | windows: http://superuser.com/questions/39800/how-would-i-go-about-modifying-firefoxs-aboutconfig-settings-via-an-external

Answer (score 19):

[*This doesn't provide what you've asked for but is a different way to achieve the same result.*]

First, about the warning... You can make sure you never see it again (on a per profile basis) as shown below:

[image]

Now, as regards the preferences you desire. In general, you can create a simple text file called `user.js`. This file has to be placed in the relevant profile folder such as `/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/random.default` (where `random` is something unique to each user).

The structure and syntax of `user.js` is described in [User.js file](http://kb.mozillazine.org/User.js_file) for example.

So in your case, you would have a line such as:

```
user_pref("browser.urlbar.trimURLs", "false");
```

or, to use your other example (*but see further down*):

```
user_pref("browser.search.defaulturl", "https://duckduckgo.com/");
```

However, I suggest that you first ensure that the preferences you set are valid for the browser version you're using. I say this because I don't see `browser.search.defaulturl` at all in my `about:config`. I'm using Firefox 22 beta. Instead, I see:

```
browser.search.defaultenginename;Google
```

[image: Engine]

So, taking the example of using Bing instead of Google, the other line in your `user.js` if you're using Firefox 22, would be:

user_pref("browser.search.defaultenginename", "Bing");

As the image indicates, you can search for additional engines.

So, in short, you can put your preferences in `user.js` and you can remove the nag screen by unticking in the first image.

Also, as indicated in the resource I linked to, you must restart the browser for the code in `user.js` to take effect.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a possible shell script. You have to `cd` to your profile directory before using it (where the `user.js` is). Say the script is called `ff_set` you could call it like:

```
ff_set browser.search.defaulturl '"https://duckduckgo.com/"'
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i 's/user_pref("'$1'",.*);/user_pref("'$1'",'$2');/' user.js
grep -q $1 user.js || echo "user_pref(\"$1\",$2);" >> user.js
```