# Is there a way to toggle Hide/Unhide Firefox Web Browsers Title Bar via Command Line?

Tags: command-line, firefox

Is there a way to toggle Hide/Unhide Firefox Web Browsers Title Bar via Command Line?

It is possible via the Firefox Web Browser's GUI:

1. click on top right 3 horizontal lines (☰)
2. click on Customize
3. Untick "Title Bar"

[image: Firefox Customize GUI]

I have gone through `man firefox` but did not get any information on how to achieve this via Command Line.

Ubuntu 18.04.3 & Ubuntu 19.10

Due to some demanding reasons, one of the reason is below

I need to use Hide top bar Extension but not all the time.. So I would like to toggle between Hide and Unhide Firefox Web Browsers Title Bar like in below cases

1. UnHide it when Hide top bar extension is On
2. Hide it when Hide top bar extension is off

Please note that:

I am Ok.. if it is not possible with CLI.. I just want to make sure is there a way or not with CLI

Comment: Maybe `user_pref("browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar", true);` in your prefs.js?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.. I am looking for a command line.. the way you guide seems tougher than GUI way I mentioned in Q

Comment: I set it once via the GUI and never bothered with it  again. But since, for whatever the reason which isn't clear to me, you want to do so from the command line, you could possibly use `sed` to change false to true for that particular line.

Comment: seems the right way.. the reason is I am customizing the ISO.. so straight away whoever installs with this ISO will not bother like you said you never bothered.. Thank You @DKBose

Comment: You are asking an XY question. The answer to your current question, "How to edit the firefox preferences with the terminal" is not the appropriate approach to do what you really want, shipping a customized firefox version on an ISO.

Comment: @vanadium thanks for your response.. Please dont consider it as XY.. I have just explained DKBose bcoz he is not clear.. My Q is still the same.. via CLI.. I am OK if its not possible with CLI..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change Firefox's \`about:config\` from a shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313483/how-do-i-change-firefoxs-aboutconfig-from-a-shell-script)

Comment: @vanadium thanks for your response.. Please dont consider it as XY.. I have just explained DKBose bcoz he is not clear.. My Q is still the same.. via CLI.. I am OK if its not possible with CLI..

Comment: Thank you. The use case you now have added to your question makes a lot of sense as to why one could want this.

Comment: Found the answer. However, it does not appear possible to apply changes through the command line " on the fly" .

Answer (score 1):

Firefox stores user preferences in the file `prefs.js` in the user's profile directory. That file should not be edited while firefox is running. Changes in preferences are written when firefox exits.

A script that edits the file `prefs.js` to change the setting "browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar" would therefore be needed to change the setting that enables or disables the legacy title bar using the command line. The setting appears as:

```
user_pref("browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar", true);
```

Configuration options can also be set using a file `user.js` in the profile folder. Preferences set in `user.js` have preferences over the settings in `prefs.js`. Any changes using the preferences dialog or using `about:config` will be lost when Firefox is restarted, so that file is a means to set more permanent default options in a user profile ([Ref](http://kb.mozillazine.org/User.js_file)).

The change will only take effect the next time firefox is loaded. I am not aware of a possibility to reload the configuration files "on the fly" (nor are [these specialists](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/178116-closed-how-to-change-a-setting-in-firefox-without-using-the-gui/)) so a change would immediately take effect in the running Firefox instance. The best you can do, afaik, is have your script terminate Firefox, apply the change in `user.js` using your script, then reopen Firefox.